# Get every second element of array with array methods

Tags: javascript, arrays

for learning purposes I want to get every second element of an array. I succeeded with a for loop:

```js
  const numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];

  function filterEverySecond(arr) {
    let everySecondEl = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i += 2) {
      everySecondEl.push(arr[i]);
    }
    return everySecondEl;
  }

  console.log({
    numbers,
    result: filterEverySecond(numbers)
  });
```

Now I want to achieve the same without a for loop, but by using array methods (forEach, filter, map or reduce). Can anyone recommend which method would be best here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do it easily with `filter`

```js
const numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];

const filtered = numbers.filter((_, i) => i % 2 === 0)

console.log(filtered)
```

you just filter out the elements that have a odd index

Comment: Now it looks so obvious... Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `filter` and check if the index of the current array element is divisible by 2:

```js
const numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];

console.log({
  numbers,
  result: numbers.filter((_, index) => index % 2 === 0)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a for each loop like so to get the same desired output:

```js
const numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
const result = [];

numbers.forEach(number => {
    if (number % 2 != 0) {
        result.push(number);
    }
});

console.log(numbers);
console.log(result);
```

The modulus operator returns the remainder of the two numbers when divided. For example: `1 % 2` will return `1` as the remainder. So in the if statement we are checking if the number is not divisible by `2`.

Comment: Hey there! Your answer seems to be wrong, author of question wanted result: `[ 1, 3, 5, 7, 9 ]` and not your one, fix code before you get more down votes.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, simple fix!

Answer (score 0):

You can use filter for index.

```
const numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
console.log({
    numbers,
    result: numbers.filter((n,i)=>i%2==0)
});
```